# How should I approach counting wins per team over a series of matches in R?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I'm seeking advice about how to think about and approach this problem.

I have a data-frame structured like this one, with many pairs of teams playing multiple matches per round over multiple rounds. I want counts of wins, losses, and ties per team for the whole season (= the whole data-frame).

[image]

I've thought of two approaches, but neither of them seems right:

1. I can think through comparing two given scores to determine win/loss/tie for one of them, using an if-then-else function. But sometimes the other score for a match is the one below, and sometimes it is the one above. So looping through with an `apply`function seems not right.
2. Alternatively, I could use `dplyr` functions to group by round, and compare within the round. But then with what function? I don't want to use a summarize function like `dplyr` seems to naturally work with, because I want to generate a column that tells me whether each of several cells is a win.

Any advice, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt. I initially out the data in a long format with `melt()`. Then, I created a group variable in `group_by()`. Then, I changed the order of each pair using `value`, which is the scores in the match. In `mutate()`, I assigned "ties" when two values (two scores) are equal. Otherwise, I assigned "win" and "lose" to each pair since the winner comes in the first place. If you want to have a wide format, you can do that using `dcast()`.

```
mydf <- data.frame(round = c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2"),
                   team = c("Lincoln", "Jefferson", "Washington", "Adams"),
                   match1 = c(3, 2, 5, 0),
                   match2 = c(1, 1, 3, 1),
                   match3 = c(2, 4, 4, 3),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

melt(mydf, id.vars = c("round", "team"), variable.name = "match") %>%
    group_by(round, match) %>%
    arrange(desc(value)) %>%
    mutate(result = { if(value[1] == value[2]){"ties"}else{
        c("win", "lose")}
    })


#    round       team  match value result
# 1     A1    Lincoln match1     3    win
# 2     A1  Jefferson match1     2   lose
# 3     A1    Lincoln match2     1   ties
# 4     A1  Jefferson match2     1   ties
# 5     A1  Jefferson match3     4    win
# 6     A1    Lincoln match3     2   lose
# 7     A2 Washington match1     5    win
# 8     A2      Adams match1     0   lose
# 9     A2 Washington match2     3    win
# 10    A2      Adams match2     1   lose
# 11    A2 Washington match3     4    win
# 12    A2      Adams match3     3   lose
```

Answer (score 2):

You are in a format that is long with respect to rounds but wide with respect to matches.  I would use rank to find which team is higher,  per match using `sapply`,  per round using `ave`:

```
sapply(mydf[-1:-2], function(x) ave(x, mydf[1], FUN=rank))
#     match1 match2 match3
#[1,]      2    1.5      1
#[2,]      1    1.5      2
#[3,]      2    2.0      2
#[4,]      1    1.0      1
```

2s are wins, 1 are losses, 1.5s are ties. You might use `factor()` to label them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another dplyr/tidyr option

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  gather(match_number, score, 
         match1:match3) %>%
  group_by(round, match_number) %>%
  mutate(percent_goals =  score / sum(score),
         win = percent_goals > 0.5,
         tie = percent_goals == 0.5,
         lose = percent_goals < 0.5) %>%
  gather(outcome, test, 
         win, tie, lose) %>%
  filter(test) %>%
  count(team, outcome) %>%
  spread(outcome, n, fill = 0)
```